# How to properly prepare text data for processing it by already trained Naive Bayes multinomial model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I trained a Naive Bayes multinomial model for binary classification of text for the presence of personal data in it. 
`model = MultinomialNB() model.fit(X_train, y_train)`

I can't figure out how to use the already trained model to be able to check any text.  An error occurs with this action `y_pred = model.predict(new_X_test)` - "ValueError: X has 1 features, but MultinomialNB is expecting 6328 features as input.". As I can understand this is related to the `CountVectorizer` text preprocessor (`from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer`)

For example: 
`X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['sentence']) X.shape` 
returns: 
`(1600, 6328)` 
the object `X` has 6328 features 
`X` is the same as the `X_train` on which the model was trained.

So, in order to test the new text on this trained model, I need to process it (using `CountVectorizer`) in such a way that the object I will feed to the model has 6328 features.

But I don't understand at all how to do it.
Or maybe I'm wrong about something?

Comment: You need the vocabulary from when you originally trained the CountVectorizer. It needs this information to know which words go with which features. Do you have the original CountVectorizer, or its vocabulary?

Comment: Nick, your question has lead me to the problem: instead of using the original vertorizer I've created new one. Now I use the old one and process data within it not by `vectorizer.fit_transform` method but by `vectorizer.transform` one. I still cannot fully understand what I'm doing but now everything works.